# How can i run specific widget in background using flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart

i am looking for good way for running specific widget in flutter app background

for example like that one in Facebook messenger. when someone send message.  a pop up circle avatar being displayed

so How can I implement this

Comment: You might be looking for background services.

Comment: FCM can help you.

Comment: @GursewakSingh @ 
Yeasin Sheikh ..is FCM the same background services ?